# Multiplicar elementos de una misma clase jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

tengo el siguiente problema necesito multiplicar dos valores de acuerdo a su clase pero tengo más de dos cajas donde están los valores que se van multiplicar, la multiplicación nada más me la hace una vez aquí está mi código

```
<div>
  <div class='mult'>
    <input type="number" class="unitario" id="unitario">
  </div>
  <div class='mult'>
    <input type="number" class="cantidad" id="cantidad">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="total" readonly>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class='mult'>
    <input type="number" class="unitario" id="unitario">
  </div>
  <div class='mult'>
    <input type="number" class="cantidad" id="cantidad">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="total" readonly>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".mult input").keyup(multInputs);

    function multInputs() {
        $(".mult").each(function() {
            var $cantidad = $(".cantidad").val();
            var $unitario = $(".unitario").val();
            var $total = $cantidad * $unitario;
            $(".total").val($total);
        });
    }
});
```

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que dice azteca es verdad pero si te entendi bien lo que quieres hacer se puede si metes los dos input en el mismo div y luego te posicionas en el con un selector jQuerry o getElement y buscas sus hijos por el indice [0] y [1], luego con un bucle for haces la operacion n veces saludos...

Comment: Puedes formular la respuesta y que sea aceptada para que le sirva a alguien más en un futuro.

Answer (score 0):

RTFM: https://api.jquery.com/val/

Al seleccionar el valor de un selector (Múltiple en tu caso) solamente agarra la primera incidencia, osease `var $cantidad`, `var $unitario` y `var $total` solamente funcionaran en la parte de arriba de tu HTML

Comment: ¿entonces como lo puedo que haga la operación N número de veces?